# Extract specific value from block of data

Tags: awk, grep, xml

I have the following block of data and need to extract the percent value in XYZ FREEBYTES, i.e. captured value should be equal to 64. As far as I know, I can grep and cut the data. However, the digits are not fixed. How can I extract the variable percent value in the below block please?

```
<ab type="global" id="80" totalid="80" intervalms="2150804.595">
    <contraction type="tenured" amount="4325376" newsize="1081330176" timetaken="6.373" reason="space following ab" />
    <finalization objectsqueued="2683" />
    <timesms mark="546.032" sweep="11.013" compact="0.000" total="564.779" />
    <XYZ FREEBYTES="700212376" totalbytes="108133017" percent="64" >
      <abc freebytes="696214000" totalbytes="107700531" percent="64" />
      <efg freebytes="3998376" totalbytes="432486" percent="92" />
    </XYZ>
  </ab>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -oP 'FREEBYTES.*percent="\K[0-9.]+' file
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed -n '/FREEBYTES/{s/.*percent="\([0-9.]*\).*/\1/p}' file
```

Or GNU `sed`:

```
sed -rn '/FREEBYTES/{s/.*percent="([0-9.]+).*/\1/p}' file64
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk '/FREEBYTES/{sub(/.*percent="/,""); sub(/".*/,""); print}' file
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*FREEBYTES.*percent="([0-9.]+).*/\1/' file
```

Note that all of these will work on arbitrary input of varying lengths as long as the strings `FREEBYTES` and `percent="` are present and followed by at least one number and then a `"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -F[=\"] '/<XYZ FREEBYTES/ {print $9}'
```

This will find the line with `<XYZ FREEBYTES` match and print 9th filed with delimiter `=` and `"`.

Answer (score 0):

any field can be pick up from an XML file, for instance with `xyz.xsl` having

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output type="text" />

<xsl:template match="//XYZ">
  <xsl:value-of select="@percent" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

a mere `xsltproc xyz.xsl foo.xml` would yield

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>




    64
```

I admit this is a bit longer, and you have to filter out `<?xml..>` line, however in the ong run xml file are easiest to process.

Answer (score 0):

Using XMLstarlet to extract the value of the `percent` attribute of the `XYZ` node:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//XYZ/@percent' file.xml
```